# How to change iOS share feature text for my App?

Tags: ios, share

I am looking for a way to dictate how my app is displayed in the iOS share feature window.

Currently opening the share feature from a different app (like Notes) will display my app with text that reads "Copy to ". I'm looking to change this to something like "Open with " or "Import to ".

The developer API pages do not seem very good though, and I have not been able to find a great answer. I imagine its some property in the info.plist, established upon installation, but I can't find out what that property might be.

Has anyone here done something like this before?

Attached image just grabbed off Google to show the text I'm talking about:
[image of text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gWPH.png)